# Escaping tags <#> in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to compose a stylesheet in which in the Message tag I need to have 
the following text: `<#> $param\n$otherParam`, but I don't know how to escape the  `<#>` part? Can someone help me?

Using xslt 2.0.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Request  xmlns="">
        <Message></Message>
    </Request>
```

The final message should look like this:

```
<#> 1234
AbY5256
```

Comment: Can you show your **input** ?

Comment: There's no input. I'm just giving the xslt parameters as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape a `<` use `&lt;` and for `>` use `&gt;`

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <Request  xmlns="">
    <Message>&lt;#&gt; 1234
AbY5256</Message>
  </Request>
```

Or maybe this, if you wanted to make explicit the fact you want a line-break

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <Request  xmlns="">
    <Message>&lt;#&gt; 1234&#10;AbY5256</Message>
  </Request>
```

Comment: Turns out there's a problem -my program formats the code and the new line disappears.                                                                                                                           <Message>&lt;#&gt; <xsl:value-of select="$code"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$id"/>
</Message> -how it look like. I've tried as mentioned and with        
 <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text> but after it's formated it becomes <xsl:text/> and I still cant get a new line. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try doing `<xsl:text xml:space="preserve">&#10;</xsl:text>`

Comment: Note that you shouldn't really have to add `xml:space` here, as the XSLT specification states whitespace should always be preserved in `xsl:text` elements. However, some (older) processors, like MSXML, don't adhere to this unfortunately.